# How to find basic algebra conversion formula?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm doing some programming for a video game in which the player characters and monster enemies can move at different speeds on 2-dimensional, cell-based tile map. Examples of these speeds are as follows:

```
1600 ms = 0.625 tiles/s
1000 ms = 1 tile/s
800 ms = 1.25 tiles/s
400 ms = 2.5 tiles/s
100 ms = 10 tiles/s
25 ms = 40 tiles/s
```

The same mathematical formula is used to convert every one of the above equations (feed the formula the first value, out pops the second). Problem is my math skills are terrible and I can't figure out how to determine what that formula actually is. Help!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second value = 1000/first value.